# How to import mdf file into Azure Data Studio

Tags: sql-server, macos, azure, azure-sql-database

I installed Azure Data Studio on my Mac and I have an existing database in `.MDF` format.

How can I add this database to the databases list in Azure Data Studio?

Comment: SQL Server doesn't run _on a Mac directly_ so there's no way for Azure Data Studio alone to do anything with your .mdf file (and why on earth do you have an .mdf file instead of a .bak file?). You can attach an .mdf file to an instance of SQL Server running in a Docker container (see [this](https://sqlblog.org/2016/11/16/s1-vs-code-mac-sql-linux-docker) and [this](https://sqlblog.org/2020/03/15/attaching-restoring-databases-inside-a-container)) but it is much better and safer to restore a backup (see [this](https://sqlblog.org/2015/04/07/s1-bad-habits-file-backups)).

Comment: Hi @Adi, did you solve it now?

Comment: Yes, Thanks to everyone!
I copied the files into the Docker, and then I ran a query to create the database from this files.

Comment: Hi @Adi, Congratulations you have solved it. I post it in my answer, then we all could know that.  You can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score -2):

Others have post same questions, here's the solution:

Azure Data Studio is like SQL Server Management Studio: these are client programs that access SQL Server, but ADS and SSMS don't touch the MDF files directly.

What you need is SQL Server to open the MDF. Try [downloading SQL Server Developer Edition](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sql-server/sql-server-downloads) - it's free. Once it's installed, follow the [instructions on how to attach a database](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-2017). Attaching a database is kinda like opening a .doc file in Word - you need Word installed first.

Ref here: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/221488/how-do-i-upload-an-mdf-file-to-azure-data-studio-for-mac

Congratulations you have solved it:

"Yes, Thanks to everyone! I copied the files into the Docker, and then I ran a query to create the database from this files."

Comment: Question is tagged [tag:macos] - can't install Developer Edition there.